# Python calling a (fortran) library that uses MPI

Tags: python, mpi

I'd like to load and call a library that uses MPI.
i would imagine that each rank loads its own version of the library and then the libraries would communicate to each other. I don't want to do any communication or MPI handling from the library caller. 
The python code would remain the same no matter if I load a library that uses mpi or a library that use openmp for instance. I manage to make it work when I dynamically load and call the library from C. But with python it fails with :

> mca: base: component_find: unable to open
>   /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/openmpi/mca_paffinity_hwloc: perhaps a missing
>   symbol, or compiled for a different version of Open MPI? (ignored)

[..]

> It looks like opal_init failed for some reason;

[..]

> opal_shmem_base_select failed   --> Returned value
>   -1 instead of OPAL_SUCCESS 
>   ompi_mpi_init: orte_init failed   --> Returned "Error" (-1) instead of "Success" (0)

[..]

I wonder what I have to do for it to for with python. Something like recompiling python with openmpi?

I give an example below:

**testMPI.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from ctypes import *
# Loading library
raw = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libtest.so.1.0')
print "hello world "
raw.test()
```

**test.f90**

```
subroutine test() bind(c,name='test')
    use MPI
    implicit none
    integer :: nprocs =-1 !< total number of process 
    integer :: rank=0    !< rank in comm world
    integer :: ierr =-1  !< 
    call MPI_init(ierr)
    call MPI_comm_size(MPI_comm_world, nprocs, ierr)
    call MPI_comm_rank(MPI_comm_world, rank, ierr)
    write(*,*)"hello world from ",rank," of ",nprocs
    call MPI_finalize(ierr)
end subroutine
```

**Makefile**

```
FC=mpif90.openmpi
FFLAGS=-free -fPIC -g -Wall 
all: obj test
test:
    mpirun.openmpi -n 4 ./testMPI.py
obj:
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c test.f90
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -shared -Wl,-soname,libtest.so.1 -o libtest.so.1.0 test.o
clean:
    rm *.o libtest*
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, there is a work around for this : 
when you run configure for compiling openmpi, use the following flag:

./configure --disable-dlopen

Hope it works for you!

Comment: You might consider adding some [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your answer to improve its quality.

Comment: I'm a bit busy but I'll come back and accept it as soon as I try it. Thanks!